# Unable to locate dropdown created by jQuery plugin

Tags: c#, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am writing an automation test script in **C#** using **Selenuim Webdriver** where I need to click on two dropdowns one by one. Here is the HTML source code of the two dropdown elements:

```
<select id="ServiceTypeId" class="chosen chzn-done" tabindex="-1" name="ServiceTypeId" style="display: none;"></select>
    <div id="ServiceTypeId_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single">
        <a class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)"><span>Choose an Option</span></a>
        <div class="chzn-drop"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
<select id="PropertyTypeId" class="chosen chzn-done" tabindex="-1" name="PropertyTypeId" style="display: none;"></select>
    <div id="PropertyTypeId_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single">
        <a class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
        <div class="chzn-drop"></div>
    </div>
```

I am able to successfully locate an element in the first dropdown (ServiceTypeId) by CssSelector like this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.chzn-container a.chzn-single")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.chzn-drop li.active-result"))[5].Click();
Thread.Sleep(500);
```

But I am unable to locate the second dropdown(PropertyTypeId) as they both have the same classes applied to them.

I tried using to locate them using their ID but its not working:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("PropertyTypeId_chzn")).Click();
```

I think this plugin has been used to create the dowpdowns: [jQuery plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Can someone please help me find a way to do this?

**EDIT:**
The two elements are set to `display:none` and hence when I am trying to click them using `driver.FindElement(By.Id("ServiceTypeId")).Click();` I am getting the error:

> Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution to this and would like to share it as it may help someone else facing similar issue.
The main problem was that the elements were set to `display:none` and so before clicking them they should be made visible. I can be done using JavaScript like this:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('ServiceTypeId').style.display = '';");
Thread.Sleep(500);

driver.FindElement(By.Id("ServiceTypeId")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(300);

js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('PropertyTypeId').style.display = '';");
Thread.Sleep(2000);

driver.FindElement(By.Id("PropertyTypeId")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(500);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try css3 pseudoselector

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("select:nth-of-type(1)")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter how these dropdowns were created, problem with selector i think. BTW, if in future you want to select value from dropDowns don't forget to click on dropDown first, then select value from it. Anyway, next code should work:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#ServiceTypeId"));
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#PropertyTypeId"));
```

**UPDATE**

```
//Click on first a link then li will appear in div. Click on 6th elem
driver.findElement(By.CssSelector("#ServiceTypeId_chzn > a")).click();
driver.findElements(By.CssSelector("#ServiceTypeId_chzn .chzn-drop > li"))[5].click();
//Same for second
driver.findElement(By.CssSelector("#PropertyTypeId_chzn > a")).click(); 
driver.findElements(By.CssSelector("#PropertyTypeId_chzn .chzn-drop > li"))[5].click();
```

Comment: I have edited and added some more info to my question. The point is that ServiceTypeId and PropertyTypeId are set to display:none

Comment: Well, but you able to locate first element even it's display == none. Possibly i made a mistake in selector (it's very difficult guess full html structure and behaviour after click then you not able to see it). Let's try again. Please try next selectors and let me know whether they work or not.).

Comment: Answer has been updated, please take a look at it. Hope this will help you.